# Shell nested variable not recognized

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am trying to run a shell script which takes 1 argument `<filename_with_extension>`
and it should rename it to the `<filename>`
for example I pass a file named `myFileXX._copying_` and I want it to be renamed to `myFile.XX`

I am trying:

```
mv "/user/source/$1" "/user/source/${$1%._copying_}"
```

but not working.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` to your script file. It will cause the shell to dump out commands as they are executed. It can be very helpful to see the results of variable substitutions. Alternatively: `sh -x yourfile.sh myFileXX._copying_`

Comment: You should show your script, and not a line from it. And *"but not working"* is not a good problem statement. You should provide the details. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Do you want to lowercase the filename, too?

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question, I only want to remove "._COPYING_"

Comment: XX is a static string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mv "/user/source/$1" "/user/source/${1%._COPYING_}"
```

worked

Comment: It won't put dot before `XX` to make it `myFile.XX`

Answer (score 2):

The format of your [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) `${$1XX%._copying_}` is incorrect. That should be `${1%._copying_}`

> [${var%Pattern}](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
>        ${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.

Comment: Read the question again "*renamed to myFile.XX*".

Comment: @Nic3500, fady taher said in the comment that he just want to remove the extension. I just edited the question to add this clarification.

Comment: ah ok, question does not fit comments, sorry.